# Trouble with populating listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I am trying to populate a listview with custom made objects. I am using an 
adapter to use the listview class. The following is the code I use to use the adapter.

```
    adapter = new SearchListAdapter(this, values);
    expListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SearchList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

In the SearchListAdapter class I have the following code:

```
public class SearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> values;
    public SearchListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> UsernameValues) {
        super(context, R.layout.search_contact, UsernameValues);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = UsernameValues;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_contact, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        for(String Index : values)
        {
            textView.setText(Index);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I can see that the setListAdapter is working (I assume), as it is passing the information into the SearchListAdapter, but when the getView tries to populate the list, it just enters the last String value from the ArrayList in every single element in the list. What am I missing to make it so every single element corresponds to a value in the ArrayList? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
for(String Index : values)
{
    textView.setText(Index);
}
```

is actually iterating over your complete data `List` and setting each value at every iteration. So, after the last iteration, every `textView` is left with the last value in your adapter's backing `List`.

What you need is to only set that value that corresponds to the current row `position` of your `ListView` in your `UsernameValues` list.

```
textView.setText(values.get(position));
```